# When publishing a Google Sheet add-on, is cell formatting included?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I have created a Google Sheet add-on that includes a bunch of Google Apps Scripts plus a bunch of formatting over a number of sheets (tabs).  When I publish this to the G Suite Marketplace, will that formatting of the sheets (tabs) be included?  For example, I have entered column headers, styled the text (colour, font etc).  The formatting and text instructs the user where to enter the needed data that allows the add-on to function.

I have searched through the documentation and other Stackoverflow questions, but have not found a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. @Rubén was likely referring to this solution.

To accomplish this, follow these steps.

1. Create your spreadsheet with associated formatting, text, colours etc.
2. Go into Share settings and share the spreadsheet with the option `Anyone who has the link can view`
3. Then grab the ID of the spreadsheet within the URL (ex. [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**ID_IS_HERE**/edit#gid=0](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/__ID_IS_HERE__/edit#gid=0))
4. To copy that spreadsheet use the following code in your add-on.

   ```
   function importSheet() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet ID goes here");  
       var sheetToCopy = ss.getSheets()[0];  //gets the first sheet
       var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
       sheetToCopy.copyTo(destination);  
   }
   ```

If your source spreadsheet has multiple sheets, you can get the number of sheets using `var number = ss.getSheets().length;` then loop through the above code using `number` to copy each individual sheet.

Regarding the source spreadsheet, Google provides the following detail

`// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
// It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).`

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The published Google Sheets add-ons doesn't include a copy of the spreadsheet. To include them you could make that your add-on creates a copy of the spreadsheet that includes the formatted sheets or you could publish that spreadsheet as a template.

Reference

- [Create a file from template](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148833?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
  Look at the *Create a template with an add-on* section

Comment: Reading through the link you provided seems like templates are user specific, rather than shared through a G service of some sort.  I also can't see how to import or include a sheet with the add-on.  I'll continue to research, thanks for your input.